# Applescript: string might have a quote

Tags: applescript

I've got an Applescript file that in part of it checks an API for a string. That string may have a quote in it. When it doesn't the script works fine, when it does have a quote the string fails. How can I safeguard the string so it works in either case?

This works:

```
string = "Yeah working"
```

This doesn't:

```
string = "Yeah I'm working"
```

How can I escape that quote mark when I don't know where it'll be or if it'll be there?

Comment: How are you fetching the string?  AppleScript typically does not have a problem with single quotes, but anything that communicates via the shell often does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string isn't a legal variable name for starters. Other than that,  `set myString to quoted form of "Something own's a quote"` should do the trick.